# Bad practice to use Runnable as callback / subroutine?

Tags: java, callback, runnable

Is it's considered bad practice to use `Runnable` as a callback?

Considering that `Runnable` is meant to be used with threads (see it's JavaDoc), I'm wondering if this is okay - or whether I should make my own interface for this purpose.

What I'm talking about is something like:

```
public class KeyBinding {
    public KeyBinding(KeyStroke stroke, Runnable handler) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, Runnables can be used for any purpose.

"The general contract of the method run is that it may take any action whatsoever"([Runnable javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html))

Generally, it should not be bad practice, definitely better practice than creating an extra unnecessary interface in your own code.

Comment: On the other hand, looking at the doc link you give, it says `The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.` So, as KajMagnus experienced, people might expect the Runnable to be associated with a thread, and find this usage confusing. I agree with KajMagnus that defining an Interface specific to this usage is clearer.

Comment: Actually, It is always associated with a thread, the main thread!

Answer (score 27):

Don't use Runnable as a callback; it might cause confusion: people and code quality tools sometimes expect it to be used with threads only.

I did myself use Runnable as a callback — I thought it seemed fairly well suited for use as a generic callback. A month later someone found my code snipped:

```
doneCallback.run();
```

and he noticed that the `doneCallback` was a `Runnable`, and that invoking `.run()` directly resulted in a warning in our code quality analysis program (Sonar). So, to fix the warning?, or because he thought the intention was to create a thread?, he forked a new thread, and called `run()` via that thread instead.

However, forking a thread there, broke stuff.

To avoid confusion, now I'm instead creating a generic callback interface that's not related to threads in any way. I'm just adding a class `Callback` with a method `call`. I think I'd better not use `java.util.concurrent.Callback` because that one is related to threads too.

Comment: This has been really helpful! thanx a lot ^^