# functional interface that takes nothing and returns nothing

Tags: java, function, java-8

Is there a standard functional interface in the JDK that takes nothing and returns nothing? I cannot find one. Something like the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Action {
  void execute();
}
```

Comment: Already answered and accepted, but this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23868733/1441122 . That other question is kind of hard to find, though.

Comment: Indeed - I edited that other question to make it more generic (i.e., basing the question on a a C# method).

Comment: I disagree with the use `Runnable` advice. It miscommunicates intent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741622/501113

Answer (score 284, accepted):

How about Runnable :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    /**
     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
     * thread.
     * <p>
     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
     * take any action whatsoever.
     *
     * @see     java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I've forgotten the good old interfaces and looked only in [java.util.function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: Huh, `public abstract` in an interface? Tisk tisk, JDK people! (Never noticed that before.)

Comment: I think it used to be [mandatory once upon a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface).

Comment: FWIW... while it satisfies the functional requirement, it does not sound very semantic, Runnable is commonly associated with creating threads. A simple Worker funcional interface with a doWork method would have been nice. EDIT: Oops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973294/function-with-no-args-and-no-return-type-void-in-java-8?lq=1#comment44339647_27973294

Comment: I used `Runnable` in this way, and then someone saw this Runnable, and thought "runnable, aha, threads" and edited the code and forked a thread. That resulted in a bug. So nowadays I don't use `Runnable` as a callback. Related question (well, answer): http://stackoverflow.com/a/30183786/694469

Comment: I think this interface will confuse developer, they will think that the function will do something with Threads

Comment: Quoting the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html): `The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.`
I wouldn't recommend using `Runnable` just for the purpose of no parameter, void-returning functional interface.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist That quote does not mean that the `Runnable` interface cannot have other uses that do not involve Threads.

Comment: @Eran
Of course, it doesn't. The thing is, many, many developers noticing a `Runnable` might think that this involves some threading logic and find the code confusing.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist Well, `Runnable` is the only functional interface in the JDK having a method with no parameters and void return type. You can either use it whenever you need such interface, or you can define your own interface for cases you think the `Runnable` interface is not appropriate for.

Comment: @Eran I totally agree, it's the only "suitable" functional interface in the JDK. The thing is, it's been used for years in situations, when an application required some custom threading logic. Thus usage of Runnable in non-threading specific scopes may be confusing. That's I would rather create a custom functional interface.

Comment: If you don't like the semantic of Runnable you can always use `Callable<Void>`.

Comment: @yshavit, all java interfaces have public abstract methods, it is been there from birth of java and into Java  8 : all functional interfaces have single abstract method

Comment: @RamKowsu Yeah, I was just referring to the fact that this this interface, the `public abstract` is actually written out. It usually isn't, since it's implied in interfaces. It was meant as a lighthearted comment, not anything to be taken very seriously. :-)

Comment: Optional.ifPresentOrElse introduced in java9 takes a Runnable as the second parameter without any concurrency semantics, so the official view seems to be that there's nothing wrong with using Runnable in this way